# truncating tags and displaying in seperate line?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/XgUrG/2/.. help me to get the result in different line . each data should be in new line

Comment: @davin i didnt get u ?  http://jsfiddle.net/XgUrG/5/ this is my code

Comment: @davin, magic word ? i didnt get that..

Comment: The correct word is sepArate!

Comment: JS Fiddle is a useful place for a live demo, but not a good substitute for including the code in the question. Normal punctuation and sentence structure also helps people understand your question.

Comment: @kiran: he means that you didn't say "please".  Asking for people to write your code for you doesn't generally go down well.  It's clear that English isn't your first language but you need to write your question in the form of... a question.  Questions should also be able to stand on their own - having all your code on an external site means that if that site goes down, no one can tell exactly what it is you're asking.  Read more advice on how to ask questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice.

Comment: <div id="container">
        <p ><input name="choice"  type="radio"><span>text1</span></p><p><input  name="choice"  type="radio"><span>text2</span></p><p><input  name="choice" type="radio"><span>text3</span></p></div> , i want to extract only text from this and display the result in newline (each text should be in seperate line)

Answer (score 0):

The results don't appear on separate lines because there aren't separate lines in your markup.

See http://jsfiddle.net/XgUrG/6/ which works as expected, all I changed was the markup (I pressed `Enter` a few times in specific positions).

Oh, and "magic word" is an expression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_word#Manners